# How to sort Eloquent collection after fetching results?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my controller I have this query

```
$query = Market::whereHas('cities', function($query) use ($city) {
    $query->where('id', $city);
})->get();
```

Then I want to make a few operations with this collection and remove my subquerys from the main object

```
$return['highlighted'] = $markets->where('highlighted', true);
$markets = $markets->diff($return['highlighted']);
```

The problem is when I try to sort it by `created_at`

```
$return['latest'] = $markets->sortByDesc('created_at')->take(4);
$markets = $markets->diff($return['latest']);
```

It just won't work, keeps returning the first 4 objects order by id, I've tried parsing `created_at` inside a callback function with `Carbon::parse()` and `strtotime` with no results.

I'm avoiding at all cost to make 2 different database querys since the original `$markets` has all the data that I need.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is you try to sort and take in one-go and also missing a small thing when you try to access the values of the collection.

Try below approach:

```
 $return['latest'] = $markets->sortByDesc('created_at');

 $markets = $markets->diff($return['latest']->values()->take(4));
```

Or you may need to do it like:

```
 $return['latest'] = $markets->sortByDesc('created_at');
 $return['latest'] = $return['latest']->values()->take(4);

 $markets = $markets->diff($return['latest']->all());
```

Comment: Huge mistake from my part, my original approach was working but my JSON Formatter addon messed up the real order of the collection, thank you @pr1nc3